# SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, formatting, varchar

I have this date format: 2011-09-28 18:01:00 (in varchar), and I want to convert it to datetime changing to this format 28-09-2011 18:01:00. How can I do it?

Comment: @Quassnoi it might be microsoft sql server, but i'm not 100% sure, many rdbms can be a sql server ;)

Comment: Your question seems to be slightly contradictory.  Do you want to convert a `VARCHAR` into a `DATETIME`, or do you just want to re-arrange the `VARCHAR` into a different format, but still keep it as a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Datetime columns don't have a human-readable format.

Comment: I want to convert it into datetime and change yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: @HaOx - The `DATETIME` data-type doesn't have a format.  It's not a string, it's a binary representation of a date and a time.   Do you want a `DATETIME` data-type, ***or*** do you want a `VARCHAR` data-type, with the parts of the date re-ordered?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2011-09-28 18:01:00', 120) -- to convert it to Datetime

SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @date ,105) -- italian format [28-09-2011 18:01:00]
+ ' ' + SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @date ,108 ) -- full date [with time/minutes/sec]
```

Comment: Just remember the datetime variable has no format.  You must convert it to a varchar if you want it to display in a certain format.

Comment: datetime has no format , but you have to specify it how to reproduce the text (where id the day / month ...)

Answer (score 12):

Like this

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = '2011-09-28 18:01:00'
select convert(varchar, @date,105) + ' ' + convert(varchar, @date,108)
```

Comment: `I want to convert it to datetime changing to this format 28-09-2011 18:01:00.` - Where do you use the new format?

Comment: This works but there is no need for four converts. Look at Diego's answer SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 105)

Comment: Yes, Diego's answer needs to change varchar(10) to (30). Then it will work.

Comment: @daniloquio, that is just not true

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Is `SELECT CONVERT( varchar(30), '2011-09-28 18:01:00' ,105)` what results in '2011-09-28 18:01:00'

Comment: No `SELECT CONVERT( varchar(30), '2011-09-28 18:01:00' ,105)` does nothing, it converts a string to a string, you need to pass it a datetime object.

Comment: Did you ran it in a query window? I did it and pasted the result in the comment.

Comment: @daniloquio yes i did but '2011-09-28 18:01:00' is a varchar, so you are converting a varchar to a varchar, that is why it looks correct

Comment: Oh crap, I just realized, you are totally right. (+1-1 = 0) for Diego, +1 for you. I don't know how to say it in english... la iba re cagando, I'm sorry.

Comment: It's okay, I was just pointing it out so no one would be confused.

Answer (score 12):

[this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) website shows several formatting options.

Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
```

Comment: Except that 105 doesn't include a time part.  And the OP is starting with a string, not a datetime.  This *is* helpful, but not what I'd consider a complete answer.

Comment: thanks for the comments lads. I actually just wanted to point  him in the right direction, that's why I wrote "example"

Answer (score 7):

You can have all the different styles to **`datetime conversion`** :

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

This has range of values :-

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

For style values,
Choose anyone you need like I needed 106.

Comment: Your answer seems to simply repeat the information given in an existing answer. Because of this, I've deleted your answer. If you wish to add *new* information to your answer, please edit you post then flag it for un-deletion.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way but it leaves it as a varchar

```
declare @s varchar(50)

set @s = '2011-09-28 18:01:00'

select convert(varchar, cast(@s as datetime), 105) + RIGHT(@s, 9)
```

or

```
select convert(varchar(20), @s, 105)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the below

```
select Convert(Varchar(50),yourcolumn,103) as Converted_Date from yourtbl
```

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, datetime has no format/string representational format.

You can change the string output with some formatting.

To convert your string to a datetime:

```
declare @date nvarchar(25) 
set @date = '2011-09-28 18:01:00' 

-- To datetime datatype
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @date)
```

Gives:

```
-----------------------
2011-09-28 18:01:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

To convert that to the string you want:

```
-- To VARCHAR of your desired format
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, @date), 105) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(datetime, @date), 108)
```

Gives:

```
-------------------
28-09-2011 18:01:00

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: It's not working for below format 2023-06-14 00:00:00.00000

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of all the different convert googling, ended up with this utility function that is expanded upon new variations.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseDatetime] (
    @INPUT nvarchar(255),
    @FORMAT nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS datetime

AS 
BEGIN 


DECLARE @TimePart NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DatePart NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DayPart NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ExDayPart NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @MonthPart NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @YearPart NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
--DECLARE @INPUTSTRING NVARCHAR(255)
--SET @INPUTSTRING = '20-10-2019 00:00:00'

--SET @FORMAT = 'D-M-YYYY HH:MM:SS'
IF(@FORMAT = 'D-M-YYYY HH:MM:SS')
BEGIN
    SET @TimePart = RIGHT(@INPUT,LEN(@INPUT)-CHARINDEX(' ',@INPUT))
    SET @DatePart = LEFT(@INPUT,CHARINDEX(' ',@INPUT))
    SET @DayPart = LEFT(@DatePart,charindex('-',@DatePart)-1)
    SET @ExDayPart = RIGHT(@DatePart,LEN(@DatePart)-charindex('-',@DatePart)+1)
    SET @MonthPart = left(@ExDayPart ,charindex('-',@ExDayPart )-1)
    SET @YearPart = right(@ExDayPart ,LEN(@ExDayPart )-charindex('-',@ExDayPart )+1)
    SET @Date = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearPart,@MonthPart,@DayPart) 

END

IF(@FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD')
BEGIN
    SET @DayPart = RIGHT(@INPUT,2)
    SET @MonthPart = RIGHT(left(@INPUT,7),2)
    SET @YearPart = LEFT(@INPUT,4)
    SET @Date = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearPart,@MonthPart,@DayPart) 

END

IF(@FORMAT = 'EXCEL_DAYS_SINCE_1900')
BEGIN
--DECLARE @INPUT NVARCHAR(255)
--SET @INPUT = ' 43554' 
    SET @Date = Dateadd(day,CAST(@INPUT AS INT),datefromparts(1900,1,1))
END


RETURN @Date
END
GO
```

Use it as:

```
SELECT
[DateAsDate] = dbo.[ParseDateTime]([DateAsString], 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM [tablename]
```