# SQL Convert varchar value to datetime

Tags: sql

I have a varchar value display as same as SQL date time.i need to convert this to SQL date time format.can any one help me.........

```
2014-07-28 18:05:14(varchar) --> 2014-07-28 18:05:14(DateTime)
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime

Comment: Yes - it works - as long as you have a suitable language and dateformat setting in SQL Server. Try using `SET LANGUAGE German;` before that statement - it'll crash and burn..... this string format for the date/time is **NOT** safe and can break depending on your settings. You should always use the proper **ISO-8601** date format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` with a `T` literal separating your date and time portions - this format now will work with **any** language/regional/dateformat settings in SQL Server

Comment: What "SQL" implementation do you need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select cast('2014-07-28 18:05:14' as datetime)
```

Comment: Yes - it works - as long as you have a suitable language and dateformat setting in SQL Server. Try using `SET LANGUAGE German;` before that statement - it'll crash and burn..... this string format for the date/time is **NOT** safe and can break depending on your settings

Answer (score 2):

YOU CAN TRY THIS

```
cast('2014-07-28 18:05:14' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Yes - it works - as long as you have a suitable language and dateformat setting in SQL Server. Try using `SET LANGUAGE German;` before that statement - it'll crash and burn..... this string format for the date/time is **NOT** safe and can break depending on your settings

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can try this.

`select str_to_date('2014-07-28 18:05:14');`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use

```
Convert(Varchar(20),'2014-07-28 18:05:14',106)
```

or

```
Convert(DateTime,'2014-07-28 18:05:14',106)
```

more can be described if you can provide more detail about your code.