# Convert nvarchar date to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have dates stored in a sql server database as nvarchar but I need to create a report and pull out data from the last day base on the date.

I use this when the data type is a DateTime:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE timein >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

I think I need to convert the `GETDATE() -24` to a string to compare it to the db 
The format needs to be like this:

```
April-30-15
```

Can anyone help me create a query that will select records for the past 24 hours using this date format?

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Fix your database to store date/time values in native formats rather than as strings.

Comment: I cannot change the database without breaking a program we use across the factory. I can fix the program and the dates in the future but the conversion will be part of a major upgrade down the road.

Comment: You certainly don't want to force the comparison to take place as strings if that's the format you're got to use. Or do you like dates in April coming before dates in January?

Comment: Hope this help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime

Comment: I dont know the correct syntax, but something like this is what I'm looking for:
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE timein >= DateAdd(hh, -24, CONVERT(GETDATE(), "MONTH-DAY-YEAR"))

Comment: show your table definition and some sample data. I think you are over complicating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your timeIn string to a date and compare using dates not strings. If you replace the hyphens with spaces it will be able to cast to a date. I assume you want values since the start of previous day (ignoring the current time) so I cast that to a date also.

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE cast(replace(timein, '-', ' ') as date) >= cast(DateAdd(dd, -1, GETDATE()) as date)
```

Comment: Yes, but it will be very slow if you have lots of data, as no index can be created to satisfy the query - so it will always scan the entire table.  It is [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: Agreed, as matt said, putting functions on column names in the where clause will cause scans.  It is better to rewrite the getdate to be the format of the column instead.

Comment: @Greg only problem with that is his date format does not support a `>=` comparison. So ideally you would fix the table to use a date column. In a pinch you can use my answer.

Comment: you are correct, didn't realize it was nvarchar col.