# Convert dd/mm/yyyy in String to Date format using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am writing an SQL query using SSMS where one column will return a date. However the date may come from a couple of possible sources controlled with the use of a `CASE` expression.

The first column is of datatype `varchar(8)` and is successfully converted to a date using

```
FORMAT(CAST(tlUserField1 as date),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

However my second column is `varchar(30)` and when using the same option I get the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I then tried to use

```
CONVERT (datetime2, tlUserField1, 103)
```

which returns the same error (I have also tried `date` and `datetime` with the same result)

It should be noted (not sure if this effects the outcome) that the first column is formatted as `YYYYMMDD` and the second field is `DD/MM/YYYY`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example of the strings that you're converting, it would be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: storing dates as varchar is your problem. Store them as datetime fields

Comment: maybe this is interesting reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime

Comment: examples of the strings are that the first column is YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20170719, and the second column is DD/MM/YYY e.g. 19/07/2017. i have no control over the storing of that dates as I have not designed the DB, i am trying to extract the information that has been stored there, hence i cannot change how these dates are stored and agree that they should be stored as date type fields, but they ar not and i need to convert

Comment: I suspect you have some bogus data.  If 2012+ use try_convert().  This will not generate an error, but it will return a NULL value for failed conversions.  For example Select * from YourTable where try_convert(date,dateCol,103) is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correct then you have a field that can have a date stored as varchar either like `'19/07/2017'` or like `'20170719'`

To convert a varchar field to date (not recommended using right column type is better) you can use the `convert` function. In the convert function you can add a parameter to tell the Convert function what format to expect for the convert.

More info about this function can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Basic it looks like this :

```
convert(date, datefield, 103)
```

103 is the code for British/French (format dd/MM/yyyy)

Now look at these examples

```
declare @date varchar(30) = '20170719'

select case 
  when charindex('/', @date) > 0 then convert(date, @date, 103) 
  else convert(date, @date, 112) 
end as ConvertedDate
```

second example:

```
declare @date varchar(30) = '19/07/2017'

select case 
  when charindex('/', @date) > 0 then convert(date, @date, 103) 
  else convert(date, @date, 112) 
end as ConvertedDate
```

Both will succesfully convert the varchar into a date.
Notice that I enter a different format in the @date field each time, and in the select I first determine what format to use (is there a / in the value or not) and then use the correct value for the format parameter.

**This is however not full proof offcourse since you never know what value can be in the varchar field.**

**EDIT:**

The format how the date is shown is not depending on above queries. That depends on settings of your database.
If you want to always show it as `dd/MM/yyyy` you can use the format function.

Example :

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

returns for today:

```
19/07/2017
```

in my example it would than be

```
declare @date varchar(30) = '20170719'

select format( case 
                 when charindex('/', @date) > 0 then convert(date, @date, 103) 
                 else convert(date, @date, 112) 
               end,
               'dd/MM/yyyy') as ConvertedDate
```

Comment: Thanks GuidoG, very helpful however it has led to a couple of other questions... 1) if i copy and paste your examples into SSMS and Execute it returns the date as 2017-07-19 for both examples, not as 19/07/2017 as the code 103 suggests??? 2) other than the declare statement the select queries are identical, and i missing something or are you using this to demonstrate the the same query will work for either format?

Comment: code 103 in the convert has nothing to do with how your database shows date values. That depends on your database regional settings. What my code does is convert a varchar into a date. If you want the date to show in a specific format you can use function like Format. I will edit my answer to demonstrate

Comment: Yes I am demonstrating that this same query will work for both formats