# Unable to convert dd-mm-yyyy dateformat string to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is to convert strings in the `dd-mm-yyyy` date format to datetime.

```
SELECT  
    FORMAT (CAST('11-30-2017 11:53:53' AS DATETIME), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');

SELECT  
    FORMAT (CAST('2017-11-30 11:53:53' AS DATETIME), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

If I use the date format `mm-dd-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd`, the query is executing fine. But if use the `dd-mm-yyyy` format to the `CAST` function, this error occurs:

```
SELECT  
    FORMAT (CAST('30-11-2017 11:53:53' AS DATETIME), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Why is `CAST` not able to convert the `dd-mm-yyyy` format to `datetime`?

Is there any alternative for doing this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear how Java is relevant here - presumably you see the problem in a SQL Server management console?

Comment: This question is duplicated, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184975/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-in-string-to-date-format-using-tsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below query. It may help you.

```
SELECT FORMAT (CONVERT(DATETIME, '30-11-2017 11:53:53', 103),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use convert, is specific for dates:
like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 103);
  # 07-04-2017 09:55:40.550
```

103 stands for bristish date style.

Answer (score 0):

It was already in the `format` which you want to `convert`.

Anyway try the following:

```
SELECT  FORMAT (CAST(RIGHT(LEFT('30-11-2017 11:53:53',5),2)+'-'+LEFT(LEFT('30-11-2017 11:53:53',5),2)+RIGHT('30-11-2017 11:53:53',14) AS DATETIME),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```