# How to convert a datetime column to another column using just the date part plus a hardcoded time in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, valueconverter

How can I combine the datetime column (but just the date part, not the time part of it) with a hardcoded time stamp like 06:00:00 AM? I want to convert a current datetime field using the date portion of it + the 6AM time stamp to then use in a case scenario.

For example:

```
case 
   when event_datetime > datetimefield+06:00:00 AM 
      then 'late'
```

Comment: what language is this in? You may want to add that as a tag so that people who are experts in that language can see it and answer it.

Comment: SQL, thank you. First time posting a question

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. They all use **SQL** as their query language - yet relevant differences exist. Please add a relevant tag for the **concrete RDBMS** you're using to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Convert both to DATE while in the CASE. Converting them to DATE will drop the time information. If you are using these fields again, I would recommend you convert them both to DATE, store them variables or temp table then utilize them.

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, EVENTDATETIME) > CONVERT(DATE,DateTimefield) 
    THEN 'Late'
```

Comment: thank you I thought about using that at first but since I do need to compare date and time to a datetime field I went with this:  CAST(datetime AS varchar(11)) + '06:00:00 AM' AS Induct_Planned_time. and then compare the induct_planned_time to my actual_datetime field. I am still testing it.

Comment: PostgreSQL - amazon redshift

Comment: Good luck. I don't think you can compare your VARCHAR to the DATE field without converting it back to DATETIME.  Here's how to convert your varchar back to DATE then do your comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: it did not work when I do the "case when" using the new value created. I would have to recast it back because it will be varchar and give error.

Comment: If you solve it, post an answer in your question and accept it.

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using DATEADD:

CASE WHEN event_datetime > DATEADD(HOUR,6,datetime field) THEN 'event_late'

CASE WHEN event_datetime <= DATEADD(HOUR,6,datetime field) THEN 'event_ontime'

ELSE 'event_unkwn'

END AS event_outcome

This helped me convert the datetime field to the date+06:00 AM (As date format)  for the comparison with the event_datetime to work.