# SQL Server - How to convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing StartDate in the format dd/mm/yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
I want to convert this varchar column to DATE type in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

I have tried the below.

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20),StartDate,103) AS [FormattedDate]
```

and

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(CAST([StartDate] AS DATE)),103)
```

I get the error -Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Pls suggest.

Comment: you mean the data are in both format ?

Comment: So is that StartDate column a varchar in the table?  Because DATE or DATETIME is internally stored without format. It's just depends on settings how a date/datetime/datetime2 is presented  to you by default when you select from it.

Comment: Yes, the data is stored in both the formats. Yes, it is a varchar type in the table.

Comment: Then you probably already guessed that it might be better to alter the table and make that field a DATE type.

Comment: I do not want to alter the table. Just want to select data in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: I do not want to alter the table. It is a generic table where values are stored in key value pair. I want my script to return dd/mm/yyyy format irrestpective of the format it is stored in (yyyy-mm-dd or dd/mm/yy or mm-dd-yyyy or any other). The data type of this field is varchar in the table.

Comment: @Learner what is your reason for not storing a date as a `date`? It really makes no sense. Choosing the wrong data type will almost always come back to bite you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only have the date string in dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd

```
select case when substring(StartDate, 3, 1) = '/' 
            then convert(date, StartDate, 103)
            else convert(date, StartDate, 121)
            end
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is actually quite good about figuring out formats for a date conversion with no formatting argument.  However, it is going to assume `MM/DD/YYYY` for the second format and generate an error.

So, you can use `try_convert()` and `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, startdate, 103),
                convert(date, startdate)
               )
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23884) is a SQL Fiddle.

Then, you should go into your data and fix the column.  Here is one method:

```
update t
    set startdate = coalesce(try_convert(date, startdate, 103),
                             convert(date, startdate)
                            );

alter table t alter column startdate date;
```

You can add additional formatting for the result set by turning the date back into a string, using `convert()`.

Comment: I do not want to make changes to the table. I want to just select data in the format dd/mm/yyyy for display.

Comment: The above gives me data in yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @Learner `date` data types have no format. Handle the formatting in your presentation layer.

Comment: @Learner, SSMS always displays native `date` types in yyyy-mm-dd format. You would need to convert the native date back to a string in the desired format using a T-SQL `CONVERT`, but it would be better to do that in the app code like Larnu mentioned.

Comment: Indeed. storing data as the wrong data type is always a bad design choice. Store a date as a `date`, a whole number as an `int`, a number that requires decimal places as a `decimal` etc etc. Don't use `varchar` as a one size fits all datatype, it is not.

Comment: As an example the statement `'22/03/2017' > '01/01/2020'` is true, if that data is a `varchar`. I doubt t that would be your intended behaviour.

Comment: This is a generic table where data is stored based on key value pair.

Comment: @Learner I would say most tables are "generic". In terms of SQL Server, "non-genreric" would be filestore and Graph tables. Either way, you still store a date as a `date` on any of the above. I don't really get your point.

Comment: @Learner, `SQL_VARIANT` would be the proper type in cases where you need to store different data types in the same column. But your column is named `StartDate` so it doesn't seem that column would store anything other than dates.

Answer (score 0):

To get YYYY-MM-DD use `SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 23)`

To get MM/DD/YYYY use `SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1)`

For detailed explaination try [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that first tries to convert the VARCHAR from a 'yyyy-mm-dd' format to the 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.

If that doesn't work out, then it just assumes it's already in the 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.
And then defaults to the first 10 characters from the string.

```
declare @TestTable table (StartDate varchar(10), DateFormatUsed varchar(10));

insert into @TestTable (StartDate, DateFormatUsed) values
 (convert(varchar(10),GetDate() ,103), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
,(convert(varchar(10),GetDate(), 20),  'yyyy-mm-dd')
;

select t.*,
coalesce(convert(varchar(10), try_convert(date,StartDate,20),103), left(StartDate,10)) as [FormattedDate]
from @TestTable t;
```

But [try_convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) is only available since MS SQL Server 2012.
For MS SQL Server 2008 we can use a [CASE WHEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) with a [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) to check the format.

```
declare @TestTable table (StartDate varchar(30), DateFormatUsed varchar(30));

insert into @TestTable (StartDate, DateFormatUsed) values
 (convert(varchar(10),GetDate(), 103), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
,(convert(varchar(10),GetDate(), 20),  'yyyy-mm-dd')
,(convert(varchar(19),GetDate(), 20),  'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
;

select t.*,
(case 
 when StartDate like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%' 
 then convert(varchar(10), convert(date, left(StartDate, 10), 20), 103) 
 else left(StartDate, 10) 
 end) as [FormattedDate]
from @TestTable t;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But my ssms doesnt support try_convert. I cannot change permissions. Is there an alternative pls?

Comment: @Learner Okay, I've also included a version for Sql Server 2008.