# Converting a varchar column to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a column for `dateofbirth varchar(10)`. All the data inside is stored like this `'02/01/1990'`.

I need to convert it to `datetime`. I've tried

```
CAST(DateofBirth AS DATEITME) AS BirthDate
```

But I keep getting this error when I try importing:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

I need it like this:

```
1990-02-01 00:00:00:000
```

Comment: Do you have a date in there that is not a valid date? LIke '02/31/1990' or likely a date that's '23/01/1990'. What version of SQL Server? If you are SQL2012+, you may be able to use `TRY_PARSE()` or `TRY_CONVERT()` to find your data.

Comment: This is going to be the first of many problems you have with this field. Consider changing that column to hold the informations using the `date` type. It will prevent attempts to store invalid values, it will take much less space and comparisons and ordering will work. If you don't do this, you will have to do the conversion on every value, every time, before you do anything with it.

Comment: @Shawn actually there was two rows that were missing “/“. When it was trying to convert to datetime. I updated the two rows and added the “/“, ran the code and it worked. Thanks you

Comment: Strings to Dates can be frustrating sometimes. SQL has to be able to interpret the string as a valid date. So it's important to make sure your strings didn't convert to an incorrect date. But I've always fallen back to Garbage In, Garbage Out. Sometimes you have to look at your data to see if there's garbage in it. And then figure out how to prevent that garbage. Or handle it. :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert a Varchar in format MM/DD/YYYY to a Datetime.

Sql server recognizes a set of predefined date formats that it is able to automatically parse. See [this cheat list](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).

Your input format corresponds to sql server date format 101, hence you can do :

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '02/01/1990', 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2011-09-28 18:01:00', 120) -- to convert it to Datetime SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @date ,105) -- italian format [28-09-2011 18:01:00] + ' ' + SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @date ,108 ) -- full date [with time/minutes/sec]

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do it in sql query there is syntax to do it .
Here a link ..
[SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Your cast statement works for me:

```
Declare @dateofbirth varchar(10) = '02/01/1990'
select cast(@dateofbirth as datetime)AS BirthDate
```

Result:

```
BirthDate
1990-02-01 00:00:00.000
```