# Change data type '2019-03-28 23:59:03.000000000' VARCHAR to DATETIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which stores date in `'2019-03-28 23:59:03.000000000'` this format as VARCHAR in SQL. 
I want to convert it from varchar to datetime and remove the last `000000000` values from date.

From `'2019-03-28 23:59:03.000000000'` to this `'2019-03-28 23:59:03'`.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: use `LEFT()` and `CAST() or CONVERT()`

Comment: @Squirrel, is LEFT() really needed?

Comment: possibly, the duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime

Comment: Don't store dates as text in the first place. Use the *correct* type for each kind of value. Second, there's nothing wrong with that string, that's a `DATETIME` stored in the ISO8601 format without a timezone.

Comment: The question itself doesn't make sense. Trailinig zeroes in numbers don't matter. There's nothing to remove in the first place. What *are* you trying to do? Display the datetime as a string without fractional seconds? Modify your presentation code to format the datetime properly

Comment: @MahavirKumbharvadia *why* do you want to "remove" zeroes? Most languages have no datetime type with precision so no matter what type you use, the *exact same value* will be displayed on the client. If the *client's* formatting and locale settings display milliseconds or nanoseconds, the strings displayed on screen will have trailing 0s. If not, none will appear, even if they *did* have a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show millisecs, try this one. Datetime2 let's you specify how many milliseconds you want displayed, in this case I used 0.

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME2(0), '2019-03-28 23:59:03.000000000', 121)
```

Comment: Kudos for not leaving out the style parameter of `convert`, however I would feel a lot better with my upvote if you could edit this answer to provide some explanations.

Comment: A simple CAST or PARSE will probably work as this format is *almost* the ISO8601 format.

Comment: The explanation is wrong, although `datetime2(0)` is more appropriate. Trailing fractional zeroes don't affect the value at all. The OP probably mistakes how SSMS or a client application displays dates for an actual value, and *mistakenly assumes* the type should change just to remove those (nonexistent) digits

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They don't affect the value, they affect the display of the value, as I stated.

Comment: The client application and locale settings affect the display of the value. On a client application the date most likely *won't* appear in that format, or include nanoseconds. What the OP is trying to do is pointless to begin with, there are no zeroes to remove. If anything, the OP should change the *field type* to `datetime2(0)` and stop storing dates as text

Comment: Worked .
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos took me a while to get your point. Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('2019-03-28 23:59:03.000000000', '.000000000', '') AS DATETIME)
```

when you select from your table you will

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(<YourColumn>, '.000000000', '') AS DATETIME)
FROM <YourTable>;
```

The `REPLACE()` function will remove `'.000000000'` from your string, and remains just `'2019-03-28 23:59:03'` which you will cast it as `DATETIME`

Comment: Can you explain what this statement is doing ?
It shows the output as 2019-03-28 23:59:03.000 
Not removing the last 000 zeroes ?

Comment: @MayankSharma https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d36dfeebd407130773574ed50c7e565

Comment: @MayankSharma what trailing zeros? Fractional trailing zeroes don't matter. `.0` or `.00` is the same as no fractional digit at all. It's *strings* that have trailing zeroes. You only have to handle trailinig zeroes if you try to *print* that datetime

Comment: Worked ..
Thanks a lot