# How to convert varchar to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have a datetime variable composed of the current date and a time that I would have defined.

I tried this :

```
DECLARE @limit datetime2;
SET @limit = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) + ' 05:00:00'
```

But this way doesn't work well because I can't add a `varchar` to a `date`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetime2fromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
DECLARE @limit datetime2;
SET @limit = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), '05:00:00')
select  @limit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve by using `CONCAT` in SQL

```
DECLARE @limit datetime2;
SET @limit = CONCAT(CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) , ' 05:00:00')
SELECT @limit
```