# SQL: SELECT date BETWEEN error (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    id VARCHAR,
    a_date DATE,
    logins INTEGER
);
```

I am not sure why I am getting an error when I use the following:

```
SELECT a_date 
      , SUM(logins) AS total_logins
      , VARIANCE(logins) AS varince_over_time
FROM history
WHERE
a_date BETWEEN '2018-05-10' AND '2018-05-30'
```

Even though it works perfectly fine When I run :

```
SELECT a_date 
FROM history
WHERE 
a_date 
BETWEEN '2018-05-10' AND '2018-05-30'
```

OR

```
SELECT a_date 
      , SUM(logins) AS total_logins
      , VARIANCE(logins) AS varince_over_time
FROM history
GROUP BY a_date
```

So not sure what is the actual problem with

```
SELECT a_date 
      , SUM(logins) AS total_logins
      , VARIANCE(logins) AS varince_over_time
FROM history
WHERE
a_date BETWEEN '2018-05-10' AND '2018-05-30'
```

Thanks, anything helps!

Comment: You're missing a `GROUP BY` in the last query

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need the GROUP BY if you want to use aggregate functions like `SUM`.

```sql
SELECT a_date, 
       SUM(logins) AS total_logins, 
       VARIANCE(logins) AS varince_over_time
FROM history
WHERE a_date BETWEEN '2018-05-10' AND '2018-05-30'
GROUP BY a_date;
```